# CSV import via PHP

Tags: php, csv, import

I'm importing a .CSV into an application with the following:

```
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

It sort of works but it's far from perfect. I wanted to first get out the row heads and put them into an array and then loop round each row to get the data sets in.

It seems to be having delimitting problems as the first row (heads) are also including a few parts of the second row.

I exported the .csv file straight from Excel. Wonder if there are encoding tricks etc I might be missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fgetcsv` doesnt always properly detect line endings.

Try using before the fgetcsv call:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your `1000` limit is not long enough; you should set it to a high enough value for that file ... or set to `0` for unlimited (not recommended, because it tends to be slower).

Set it to `4096` or `8192` first and see how it goes.

```
// use 8kB buffer for reading comma delimited line
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 8192, ",")) !== FALSE) {
```

**Update**

Okay, on second thought, perhaps you should inspect the file and confirm a few things:

1. Are the delimiters really a comma? (I guess you've already established this)
2. Are the string enclosures always double quotes?
3. Are strings escaped with a backslash (default) or another double quote?

Comment: Tricky thing i've got is I want to read in the first line as the headers and then attach the information to each header for further lines. But the reading of the lines seems off compared to how it's shown in Excel. I think the issue might be to do with the format it's being saved out in.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to 8192 and got same results

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 8192, ",")) !== FALSE) {
...
}
```

and then did this one and got same results

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 8192, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         $data = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why are you not using file()?

```
     $trimmed = file('somefile.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Comment: Values in CSV can contain newlines, so this approach won't work reliably.